# Как задать размеры изображения tksvg в pix?

Tags: python

**Простой пример:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import tksvg

window = tk.Tk()
svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage(master=window, file="128.svg", scale=1)
label = tk.Label(bg='#CCCCCC', image=svg_image, borderwidth=0, relief="solid")
print(label.winfo_reqwidth(), label.winfo_reqheight())
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

**128.svg - 128х128 pix.**

**Вопрос:** Как задать размеры изображения tksvg в pix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер в пикселях можно указать через параметр `scaletowidth` (или `scaletoheight`).

Из мануала Tk 8.7:

`svg -dpi dpiValue -scale scaleValue -scaletowidth width -scaletoheight height`

- `dpiValue` is used in conversion between given coordinates and
  screen resolution. The value must be greater than `0` and the default
  value is `96`.
- `scaleValue` is used to scale the resulting image. The value must
  be greater than `0` and the default value is `1`.
- `width` and `height` are the width or height that the image
  will be adjusted to.

Only one parameter among `-scale`, `-scaletowidth` and `-scaletoheight` can be given at a time
and the aspect ratio of the original image is always preserved.